# How to push notification using curl

Tags: android, firebase, cmd, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send puch notification to my android app from firefox addon or cmd or bat file. I saw many videos and posts where people do it in cmd.

I am trying to use fcm push notification using curl on windows as follows

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization:key=<key-here>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{^
More?   "notification": {^
More?     "title": "FCM Message",^
More?     "body": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",^
More?   },^
More?   "condition": True^
More? }' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

I get following error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: notification
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: title
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: FCM Message,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: body
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!,
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: condition
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 5
JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (') at position 0.
```

Can't understand what's going wrong. Can anyone please help. Is there any other way? I don't want to go to notification composer or server.

Comment: Your shell command is malformed.  You'll need to spend some time quoting the arguments correctly so the shell can understand what each argument is.

Comment: I copied this from fcm documentation

Comment: You can send feedback to the authors using the "send feedback" link at the top of every page.

Comment: @doug... I see your profile. You have amazing achievements. You should be able to help me with this. I tried out many ways but no luck. Also tried JavaScript fetch api from firefox add-on but it showed cross-origin not allowed error. Says server should have domain listed... I was wondering Can setup a little local server just for sending rcm notifications?